# Glade + Popup + instance width Python

Tags: python, glade

I have one question about Glade. Is it possible to return user-declared-information which a called with a popup-menu?

For example:
In python I call up a popup I declared with glade:

[image]

```
self.rcm = self.builder.get_object("viewport1_rechtsklick")
self.rcm.popup(None, None, None, "DATEN", event.button, time)
```

The Glade-Part looks like that: (Generated with the Glade GTK)

```
<object class="GtkMenu" id="viewport1_rechtsklick">
<property name="visible">True</property>
<property name="can_focus">False</property>
<child>
  <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="delete">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="tooltip_text" translatable="yes">Löscht das ausgewählte Schild</property>
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Löschen</property>
    <property name="use_underline">True</property>
    <signal name="activate" handler="on_delete_activate" object="viewport1_rechtsklick" swapped="no"/>
  </object>
</child>
```

Then I want to see if my "DATEN" (some data) I called up with the popup would be wrote back by glade, but the only thing I get is the MenuItem itself...

Because the MenuItem-Popup is a stand alone Script in Glade, it can be used where I want by just calling the "rcm.popup" command, but I need the Information from which object it was called to handle the "Löschen" (Delete) Command. In this Example these chessboard-pattern in the background are different GTK.IconView Objects (4 in count).

This is my Python-Code for checking if Menu-Item was activated and if the "DATEN" (some data) are wrote back from Glade, but it hasn't:

```
  def on_delete_activate(self, *widget):
      print(str(*widget))
```

"print" just shows the Menu-Item itelf:

```
<Menu object at 0xb5bd62d4 (GtkMenu at 0x87f1c30)>
```

What do I do wrong? 
Please help!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Did you think about a variable in the main program that saves the state of the dialog? You can also pass a function to the dialog that sets the variable from within the dialog.

Comment: Not exactly,  I just want to trace back witch instance called up the pop-up,  so I can make the selected menu item react on that specific object,  that was the idea...

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to do. Can you post a screenshot? and add some more explanations?

Comment: I edited the Question, sorry for my bad questioning :-/